# Global variable in iReport - Jasper subReports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Anyone know if we can set a global variables in a main report and have the sub-reports use those variables ?

In my case i have a very complicated report (Main report and then few sub-reports then in those sub-reports...other sub-sub-reports (3-5 levels like that).

Now it came to my attention that i need to pass a new variable from user input and this variable need to be used by multiple sub reports .

I know i can pass variables from Main to sub to other subs but this is a long process which i'm trying to avoid .

Any ideas ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main report create a paramter; lets say it's `$P{main_parameter}`

In a subreport create another paramter to handle `$P{main_parameter}`'s value; let it be `$P{subreport_parameter}`

now in mainreport you have   `$P{main_parameter}`

and in subreport you have `$P{subreport_parameter}`

finaly; in your mainreport right click on the subreport ->paramters -> add. That's it. Now you can pass parameter from main report to subreport.

[image]

Not: be careful both paramters' type should be same otherwise you will get error

Comment: Thank you , but i'm trying to find if there is another way to do it , since i'm have 10+ subreport it wont easy to pass them like that ... what i'm trying to do is to see if there is a way to have 1 declared in the main and it's available dynamically in the subs

Comment: afaik there is no way of dynamically pass them to subs in ireport. Since reports' format is jrxml, you can use a xml parser then do it programatically.